# p:ajax using an global HTML id to reference to an <h:messages> attribute

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, primefaces, message

I currently working on an project that needs some "rebuild" but still there is no money on this - so I have to deal with that what's in front of me. I need to display an message on every change of the radioButton as you can see in this code example:

```
<h:form>
    <h:messages id="msg"/>
    <p:accordionPanel value="#{exerciseBean.getCategoriesInGrade(5)}" var="category">
        <p:tab title="#{category.categoryName}">
            <h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="5"> 
                <ui:repeat value="#{exerciseBean.getSingleChoiceInGrade(5, category.categoryName)}" var="exercise">
                     <div>#{exercise.getText()}</div>
                     <p:selectOneRadio value="#{exerciseBean.data}" > 
                         <f:selectItems value="#{exercise.getChoices()}" var="c" itemLabel="#{c.id}" itemValue="#{c.id}"  />  
                         <p:ajax event="change" process="@this" listener="#{exerciseBean.validateInput(exercise.getId())}" update="msg"/>
                      </p:selectOneRadio>  
                </ui:repeat>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:tab>
     </p:accordionPanel>  
</h:form>
```

As you can see - inside this `<h:form>` there is directly an `<h:messages>` with the id `msg`. Now the problem: I still get the error: "cannot find component with identifier 'msg'". I now tried it with the prefix `:` but still the same problem. Is there a way to get PrimeFaces/JSF to reference to this "global-id"?

In my backend I send the message like this:

```
FacesMessage facesMessage = new FacesMessage("Right Answer!");
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, facesMessage);
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need an id for your form.
2. You then need to modify the reference to `msg` in the ajax update attribute.

So the following code change should do it for you.

1.`<h:form id="formID" >`

2.`<p:ajax event="change" process="@this" listener="#{exerciseBean.validateInput(exercise.getId())}" update=":formID:msg"/>`

Comment: Perfect answer! Thank you so much - i already tried it with using only :msg but with an fixed formID and the : it works like it should!